# How to perform previous process on a RESTful WebService call?

Tags: java, web-services, session, rest, permissions

im developing a WebApplication based on RESTful WebServices. I used the NetBeans "New File Manager" to automatically generate my "Entity Classes from database" and the "RESTful Web Services fom Entity Classes" so everything is fine and I get something like:

```
@Stateless
@Path("usuario")
public class UsuarioFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Usuario> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "TSERMEXeCommercePU")
private EntityManager em;

public UsuarioFacadeREST() {
    super(Usuario.class);
}

@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(Usuario entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

@PUT
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void edit(Usuario entity) {
    super.edit(entity);
}

@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public void remove(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    super.remove(super.find(id));
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Usuario find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return super.find(id);
}

@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Usuario> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

I have REST services for every entity on my DB. So everything is going good so far.

But I have a little problem, I need every service call to check if the user is loged in and if he has the permission to call that service, for example:

Im going to have an extra service on my UsuarioFacadeREST called logIn() that receive a user, password, and if is it correct, im going to add a "logedIn:true" parametter to his HTTPSession so i can always know if he has already loged in, something like:

```
@GET
@Path("login/{user}/{pass}")
@Produces({"application/xml"})
public String logIn(@PathParam("user") String user, @PathParam("pass") String pass, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    Usuario userEntity;
    if( (userEntity = getUserFromDB(user, pass)) != null ) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("logedIn", true);
        session.setAttribute("priviledges", loadPrivilegdesList(userEntity));
        return "<logedIn>true</logedIn>";
    } else {
        return "<logedIn>false</logedIn>";
    }
}
```

So, once he has loged in, I load his priviledges list on his session.

These privilegdes are Strings like "VIEW_CUSTOMER_LIST", "ADD_CUSTOMER", "EDIT_CUSTOMER", "DELETE_CUSTOMER", "ADD_PRODUCT", "EDIT_PRODUCT", etc, etc.

What does this means? this means that on my CustomerFacadeREST service, for every REST service(every function call), i will nedd to check the user loggedIn status and his privilegdes list. By this way i will be able to know if i can offer the user this service or i have to deny it to him.

The problem is that i think is not a good practice to edit all the autogenerated RESTful Web Services to check in every function if the HttpSession has the attribute logedIn.

So, i wish to know if is there any way to have a pre-service-call function for all the RESTful web services that check, on every service call, befor call it, the logedIn attribute of the HttpSession. I mean, I want to lock all the webServices calls and redirect them to this function so it check the things that I need to be checked and then it call the original function called by the user.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks so much for reading. Please tell me if I am not clear enough.